# Computing the period of a fraction polynomial in the number of digits

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity

So I have a fraction a/b that is known to be repeating. How do I compute the period of the repeating decimal in polynomial-time in the number of digits of A and B?

Comment: Meaning that just bashing out a long division for all the digits until it repeats is not fast enough

Comment: You might need the prime factorization of $B$.

Comment: A=1? B= semiprime? And

Comment: B doesn't necessarily have a known prime factorization

Comment: As an upper bound, the decimal must have a period less than or equal to $B$. Think about how short division works: the expansion repeats when the remainders repeat. The only choices of remainders are $0,1,2,\ldots,B-1$.

Comment: Wikipedia has a good discussion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Reciprocals_of_composite_integers_coprime_to_10

Comment: So knowing the period would be equivalent to factoring B?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Not exactly equivalent (for $1/(10^k-1)$ the period is trivial to calculate, hard to factor).  But for many (likely most) values of $B$, knowing the period will make it easy to find some nontrivial factor of $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I think this will be as hard as factoring.

If $B=pq$ is semiprime and 10 is a primitive root modulo both $p$ and $q$ (according to Artin's conjecture there should be infinitely many such primes), then finding the period $k$ of $\frac{1}{pq}$ lets you factor $B$.

In this case the period is the minimum $k$ such that $pq \mid 10^k-1$, namely $ k=\mathrm{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$.

Assume $p>q$, then either:

**Cases 1,2:** $k=p-1$ or $k=2(p-1)$, check if $k+1$ or $k/2+1$ divides $B$.

**Case 3:** $k\ge 3(p-1)>p+q-1$.
But $k$ divides $(p-1)(q-1)=pq-(p+q-1)$ so $pq\equiv p+q-1 \pmod{k}$. Once we know $p+q=A$ then we can solve for $p,q$ via $p-q = \sqrt{A^2-4B}$.

Comment: In fact if $10$ is close to being a primitive root of any prime divisor of $n$ (assuming Artin's conjecture, this will be typical) it is likely that the divisor can be extracted from $k$.  The idea is to look at random values of $\gcd(a^k-1, n)$, removing powers of $2$ from $k$ as necessary.